# Issues with User form in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, forms, microsoft-forms

I have a userform in an excel, before the users could run the macro that calls the userform without issues, however, now when trying to run the macro they get the following error message:
[image]  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDh4g.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFjop.png

That line that reference the error is this blue bar, that acts like a progress bar. I realize that the bar for some reason disappears suddenly but i dont understand why
[image]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDh4g.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3JJU.png.

Additionally, another issue when opening the file got the message and again, they could run the file without issues, ive tried adding add ins but nothing seems to work

[image]

Comment: There is likely some kind of control used on that form which is not able to be loaded - perhaps there's been a system update?   You'd have to look at the userform and figure out what's used for the progress bar

Comment: Maybe consider using Excel's status bar as a progress bar instead? There are plenty of examples on StackOverflow and it's pretty simple to do.